# Getting index of structured elements of a list into dictionaries based on regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, regex-group

I have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist = ['Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip', 'ADX_LG_24.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_24.ip', 'ADX_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_SP_24.ip', 'ADX_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.ip', 'ALM_SP_06.ip', 'K3SPG_LV_06.ip', 'K3SPG_SP_06.ip', 'KKK_LN_06.id', 'KKK_LV_06.ip', 'KKK_SP_06.ip', 'ENDCN_LV_06.in', 'ENDCN_SP_06.in', 'bCD_LV_06.ip', 'bCD_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.id', 'ADX_SP_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.id', 'ALM_SP_06.id', 'D35_LN_06.id', 'K3SPG_LN_06.id', 'K3_LV_06.id', 'K3_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LN_06.id', 'D35_LV_06.id', 'D35_SP_06.id', 'K3SPG_LV_06.id', 'K3SPG_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LV_06.id', 'bCD_SP_06.id', 'ENDCN_KD_06.in', 'ENDCN_LG_06.in', 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip', 'ADX_LG_24.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_24.ip', 'ADX_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_SP_24.ip', 'ADX_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.ip', 'ALM_SP_06.ip', 'K3SPG_LV_06.ip', 'K3SPG_SP_06.ip', 'KKK_LN_06.id', 'KKK_LV_06.ip', 'KKK_SP_06.ip', 'ENDCN_LV_06.in', 'ENDCN_SP_06.in', 'bCD_LV_06.ip', 'bCD_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.id', 'ADX_SP_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.id', 'ALM_SP_06.id', 'D35_LN_06.id', 'K3SPG_LN_06.id', 'K3_LV_06.id', 'K3_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LN_06.id', 'D35_LV_06.id', 'D35_SP_06.id', 'K3SPG_LV_06.id', 'K3SPG_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LV_06.id', 'bCD_SP_06.id', 'ENDCN_KD_06.in', 'ENDCN_LG_06.in']
# index =    0,        1,             2,          3,      4,    5,      6, ....
```

We can see the list above to be separated into two parts, delimited by `'Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3'` and `'Probes', 'Gene.symbol'`.

The regex for the components of the first and second part is:

```
([\w\d]+)_(\w\w)_(\d\d)\.(\w\w)
  rg1      rg2     rg3    rg4
```

Which should match string like this `ADX_SP_06.ip` or `K3SPG_LN_06.id`

What I want to do is to create a dictionary with keys formed by `rg1 + rg3`
where the values stored the index of the members in first and second part of `mylist`.
The results will look like this.

```
first_part_dict = {
      'bCD06'    : { 25, 26, 35, 40, 41 },
      'ADX06'    : { 6,  8,  10, 12, 14, 27, 28 },
      'ADX24'    : { 7, 9, 11, 13 },
      'ALM06'    : { 15, 16, 17, 29, 30 },
      'K3SPG06'  : { 18, 19, 32, 38, 39 },
      'KKK06'    : { 20, 21, 22 },
      'K306'     : { 33, 34},
      'ENDCN06'  : { 23, 24, 42,43 },
      'D3506'    : { 31, 36, 37 },
}

second_part_dict = {
      'bCD06'    : { 65, 66, 75, 80, 81 },
      'ADX06'    : { 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 67, 68},
      'ADX24'    : { 47, 49, 51, 53 },
      'ALM06'    : { 55, 56, 57, 69, 70 },
      'K3SPG06'  : { 58, 59, 72, 78, 79 },
      'KKK06'    : { 60, 61, 62 },
      'K306'     : { 73, 74},
      'ENDCN06'  : { 63, 64, 82, 83},
      'D3506'    : { 71, 76, 77 },
}
```

How can I achieve that with Python?

Comment: "We can see the list above to be separated into two parts, delimited by 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3' and 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol'." -- Can we see? Actually, I can't. Please specify (a) what you want, (b) what you have tried, (c) sample input, (d) actual output and (e) desired output.

Comment: Scroll further to the right or `mylist[44:46]` you can find the delimiter for the second part.

Comment: Still missing (a), (b), (c), (d) and (e).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't very elegant, but it should get the job done. I have assumed based on your expected output that you meant for the key to be `rg1 + rg3`, not `rg1 + rg2`.

```
import re, collections

mylist = ['Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip', 'ADX_LG_24.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_24.ip', 'ADX_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_SP_24.ip', 'ADX_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.ip', 'ALM_SP_06.ip', 'K3SPG_LV_06.ip', 'K3SPG_SP_06.ip', 'KKK_LN_06.id', 'KKK_LV_06.ip', 'KKK_SP_06.ip', 'ENDCN_LV_06.in', 'ENDCN_SP_06.in', 'bCD_LV_06.ip', 'bCD_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.id', 'ADX_SP_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.id', 'ALM_SP_06.id', 'D35_LN_06.id', 'K3SPG_LN_06.id', 'K3_LV_06.id', 'K3_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LN_06.id', 'D35_LV_06.id', 'D35_SP_06.id', 'K3SPG_LV_06.id', 'K3SPG_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LV_06.id', 'bCD_SP_06.id', 'ENDCN_KD_06.in', 'ENDCN_LG_06.in', 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip', 'ADX_LG_24.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_24.ip', 'ADX_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_SP_24.ip', 'ADX_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.ip', 'ALM_SP_06.ip', 'K3SPG_LV_06.ip', 'K3SPG_SP_06.ip', 'KKK_LN_06.id', 'KKK_LV_06.ip', 'KKK_SP_06.ip', 'ENDCN_LV_06.in', 'ENDCN_SP_06.in', 'bCD_LV_06.ip', 'bCD_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.id', 'ADX_SP_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.id', 'ALM_SP_06.id', 'D35_LN_06.id', 'K3SPG_LN_06.id', 'K3_LV_06.id', 'K3_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LN_06.id', 'D35_LV_06.id', 'D35_SP_06.id', 'K3SPG_LV_06.id', 'K3SPG_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LV_06.id', 'bCD_SP_06.id', 'ENDCN_KD_06.in', 'ENDCN_LG_06.in']

regex = re.compile(r'([\w\d]+)_(\w\w)_(\d\d)\.(\w\w)')
first_part_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
second_part_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
# second instance of 'Probes', to separate the first and second parts
cutoff_index = mylist.index('Probes', 1) 

for i, string in enumerate(mylist):
    matched = regex.match(string)
    if not matched:
        continue
    rg1, rg2, rg3, rg4 = matched.groups()
    key = rg1 + rg3
    if i < cutoff_index:
        first_part_dict[key].append(i)
    else:
        second_part_dict[key].append(i)
```

Result:

```
>>> first_part_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ALM06': [15, 16, 17, 29, 30], 'K3SPG06': [18, 19, 32, 38, 39], 'bCD06': [25, 26, 35, 40, 41], 'ADX24': [7, 9, 11, 13], 'ENDCN06': [23, 24, 42, 43], 'KKK06': [20, 21, 22], 'K306': [33, 34], 'ADX06': [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 27, 28], 'D3506': [31, 36, 37]})
>>> second_part_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ALM06': [55, 56, 57, 69, 70], 'K3SPG06': [58, 59, 72, 78, 79], 'bCD06': [65, 66, 75, 80, 81], 'ADX24': [47, 49, 51, 53], 'ENDCN06': [63, 64, 82, 83], 'KKK06': [60, 61, 62], 'K306': [73, 74], 'ADX06': [46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 67, 68], 'D3506': [71, 76, 77]})
```

Comment: i know rg1,rg2,rg3,rg4 are matched words ..and its returns a tuple like form ..so what   first_part_dict[key].append(i) means ?..can you explain ?

Comment: `i` is the index in the list. `key` is the `rg1+rg3` string that OP specified. Since `first_part_dict` is actually a `defaultdict(list)`, each entry of `first_part_dict` effectively starts out as an empty list. So, `first_part_dict[key].append(i)` just appends the index of `key` to the list for `key` in `first_part_dict`.

Comment: @senshin: You are right it's `rg1 + rg3`. I've updated my post. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: i didnt understood ..i just need to know what [key] acts in first_part_dict[key]? Is the index i is added to the first_part_dict?..is the matched one a number ?..i mean is key a number here ?